# jMeter maven plugin with csv input files

Tags: java, maven, csv, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I've got a working simple jmeter jmx with the plugin, reading the docs I've found how to override .properties files but right now my problem is that I have a folder with .csv files input data that I want to use in my test. The folder with the csv files is specified in an user.properties file as `inputDataFolder=path/to/folder` and referenced in the jmx like `${inputDataFolder}file.csv`. It works really fine without maven but when I run it with the verify goal it doesn't works and throws:

> `Error in NonGUIDriver org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopTestException: ModuleController:Register Fixed Customer has no selected Controller (did you rename some element in the path to target controller?), test was shutdown as a consequence`

The error suggests me a mistake defining the path to the csv folder, but I don't know how to do it correctly with the plugin. Any help is really appreciated.

PS: This is the structure that I have under `src/test/jmeter`

```
jmeter/
├── foldercsv/
├── test.jmx
├── user.properties
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got myself the answer. I digged into many post and I found that indeed it was a path issue, got it right reading this:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/maven-jmeter-plugin-users/8pTwRmMCi9I
- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59169

Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

I have maven project and configuration as:

```
src/test/jmeter/myFile.jmx
src/test/resources/testDataFiles/csv1.csv, csv2.csv etc
```

to specify csv file path in CSV Data Set Config I had to use

../../../src/test/resources/testDataFiles/csv1.csv

I tried

`../resources/testDataFiles/csv1.csv` -- didn't work
`../../resources/testDataFiles/csv1.csv` -- didn't work
`../../test/resources/testDataFiles/csv1.csv` -- didn't work

**The path worked for me is:**

```
../../../src/test/resources/testDataFiles/csv1.csv
```

**Note:**
When I run jmeter script in JMeter UI it works fine with csv file path: `../resources/testDataFiles/csv1.csv` but surprisingly this didn't work while executing the same script with Maven command.